# Tab Control switch between Tab Pages using Win API

Tags: c#, winapi, automation

I wonder if there's an easy way of switching between Tab pages of the tab control using Win API w/out using screen coordinates (a sample in c# would be highly appreciated)?

thanks.

Comment: If you *have* to use winapi then pinvoke SendMessage() to send TCM_SETCURSEL.  Getting the proper window handle would be the bigger effort.

Comment: Hi Hans could you add this comment as an aswer?

Comment: Please feel free to post your own answer and mark it as the answer.  It is only really useful with the pinvoke declarations included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the `SelectedTab` property is what you want. [Here's sample code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tabcontrol.selectedtab.aspx).

Comment: Hi, I'm looking for a Win API way as I'm automating a legacy win app and I've no access to its source code.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused when you wrote both winapi and c#, and I assumed that you were using winapi in a loose sense. (You also didn't mention that this was for out-of-process automation.) In which case System.Windows.Automation.SelectionPattern looks like what you want.

Answer (score 0):

SendMessage(hWndTabControl, TCM_SETCURFOCUS, tabIndex, 0);